# Grouping Algorithm - Tournament

Tags: algorithm, performance, grouping

Looking for an algorithm, or code if someone's feeling generous to do the following.  I need to take an input for a number of players.  The number of players will always be a factor of 4.  I want to group the individual players into groups of 4, with the least number of repetition.  The initial placement is trivial:

```
 1   2   3   4   Table 1
 5   6   7   8   Table 2
 9  10  11  12   Table 3
13  14  15  16   Table 4
17  18  19  20   Table 5
21  22  23  24   Table 6
```

So players 1-4 have "seen" each other once.  Everyone plays their game and then the players are shuffled.  On the next pass (and subsequent passes) I want to rearrange the players so that they have the least amount of overlap.  Basically, I want to prevent a player from seeing a repeated face for as long as possible, and once that is no longer possible, I want to minimize it as much as possible.

I feel like this should be a relatively simple algorithm, but every approach I end up taking feels like it's weighting itself in favor of the people that get processed first...and my gut/mind tell me that there's an absolute correct answer.

For clarity, no one is eliminated, they're just shuffled each time.

Comment: It is typical for you to at least post what you have attempted so we don't suggest something already ruled out.  You also didn't indicate what language you are using so I can't suggest an idea.

Comment: I'm using C++ but don't particularly care what language it's in.  I'm more interested in the thought process/pseudo-code.  The general approach I took initially was to loop through each "player" and seat them with people that had the lowest occurrence of sitting with them previously.  But I felt that weighted heavily toward the lower indexed players.  I can use any Java/C/C++/.NET/PHP suggestions.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a variable number of rounds...I'd imagine that wouldn't impact the correct solution very much.  In a real world example, I have 28 players and 6 rounds.  Both of which might be variable moving forward.

Comment: @JamesB41, I have an almost identical problem. with a variable number of players and a variable number of rounds. Did you ever find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up getting really lucky and only needed a practical solution for a few variants, all of which were found in this table:  http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sello/golf.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the Social Golfer Problem. There are many algorithms in the combinatorial optimization literature.

Comment: Thanks.  That was enough to go on.